# onClick Back button resets my listview

Tags: java, android, listview

So here's my problem, whenever i press the back button, my data in listview in the main activity resets. How can i retain or save the data? Here's my code for the back button

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pangalawa);
    BackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    content.setText(bundle.getString("extra_intent1"));


    BackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("debug", "button clicked");
            Intent intent = new Intent(secactivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating new instance of `MainActivity` on click of back button, so it creates Layout again and sets the list to blank.

To keep the list as previous, you should replace code in `onClick` method to

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("debug", "button clicked");
        finish();
    }
```

Also make sure when you are calling current activity from `MainActivity`, you didn't call the `finish()` method.

It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Save state :

```
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  savedInstanceState.getString("extra_intent1", bundle.getString("extra_intent1"));

 }
```

Restore state :

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  String extra_intent1= savedInstanceState.getString("MyBoolean");

}
```